# An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated 'UITransitionView' object (zombie) at address: 0x1f120730

Tags: ios7

I'm facing this issue seldon on this line in the image.

So please help me out. I've spend too much to find out. But i'm not able to find out it.

This is the actual error **[UITransitionView isDescendantOfView:]: message sent to deallocated**

[image]

This is the method in which im doing..

```
-(void)loadImageAtURLing:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recogniser
{
    [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:appDelegate.window animated:YES];

    int imgTag = [recogniser.view tag];

    NSString *str = [arrDropPinId objectAtIndex:imgTag];

    urlString = [arrLargePhoto objectAtIndex:imgTag];
    NSLog(@"Larget Image %@",arrLargePhoto);

    self.pdvc = [[PhotoDetailVC alloc] init];

    self.pdvc.isFromTVView = NO;

    if([urlString rangeOfString:@".mp4"].location == NSNotFound)
    {
        NSString *strImage = [arrLargePhoto objectAtIndex:imgTag];

        NSRange lastValue = [strImage rangeOfString:@"300" options:NSBackwardsSearch];

        if(lastValue.location != NSNotFound) {
            strImage = [strImage stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:lastValue
                                                         withString: @"800"];
        }

        self.pdvc.isVideo     = NO;
        self.pdvc.imgURL      = [strImage copy];
        self.pdvc.pinIdStr    = [str copy];
        self.pdvc.imageURLArr = [arrLargePhoto mutableCopy];
        self.pdvc.btnIndex    = imgTag;

    }
    else
    {
        self.pdvc.isVideo   = YES;
        self.pdvc.imgURL    = [urlString copy];
        self.pdvc.pinIdStr  = [str copy];
        self.pdvc.btnIndex  = imgTag;

        NSLog(@"DropPIn ARR %@",arrCheckPinId);
    }

    [self presentViewController:self.pdvc animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: So, you genuinely think we could magically guess what your problem is without you providing any code, context, etc.?

Comment: You are sending a message to an object whose memory has been reclaimed: it is no longer valid. I suggest you cover the basics of memory management in Cocoa and look for the reason it is being deallocated prematurely.

Comment: @NicolasMiari i've made property for it. But i'm not able to find out why memory is leak in this line.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Now i'm posted code. Please help me. And thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Leak is when you keep the object in memory even after you cut all references to it (can't reuse the memory). What happens here is the opposite: the memory has been recycle when you actually still need the old object. Make sure your property is defined as **strong**

Comment: Yes, Its strong @property (nonatomic,strong) PhotoDetailVC *pdvc;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i got the solution. Because this is happening UITransitionView and UITransitionWrapperView not setting the frame. So i've done this

```
self.tabBarController.view.superview.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

Comment: You can try either viewDidAppear and viewDidLoad.

Comment: viewDidAppear and viewDidLoad of presented viewcontroller? or tabbarvc?

Comment: @Erik Presented view controller. And are you getting same problem?? Can i help you ?

Comment: yes, exactly the same issue but it occurs while dismissing the presented VC. i am also presenting view controller from tabbarVC

Comment: You have to make in both viewcontroller may be helpful.

Comment: i am adding  mpmovieplayevviewcontroller view into tableview cell and i am presenting the new view controller and then dismissing it, in this case only i am gettinh the crash. if i removed the mpmovieplayercontroller, then crash didnt occur

Comment: Yea, Same issue i'm getting like this. But finally i got rid ;) .

Comment: but its not working for me. i just changed presenting the VC to pushing.